# Add hidden field at runtime

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

In Sitecore WFFM(Web Form for Marketers) - Can we add hidden field at runtime - i.e. on Submit Action and assign some value to the hidden field.
I also want to reuse this value if there is an exception on the form and user resubmits the form.

Product Details - 7.2 rev. 141226 , Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev.140117

Answer (score 0):

As the very simple, you may create hidden field like this (of course, you may provide alternative and more complex bespoke behavior for your hidden field):

```
public class HiddenField : SingleLineText
{
    protected override void DoRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.textbox.Parent.Parent.Visible = false;
        base.DoRender(writer);
    }
}
```

With the next step you need to register that field with WFFM. In order to do that just create an item for your new field:

```
/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Custom/Hidden Field
```

Within that item you specify assembly and class name for that hidden field, as is very common way to Sitecore.

So far, so good. Now you can use your hidden field as others, including adding them programmatically.

P.S. Unfortunately, I do not have an example of code for adding fields programmatically at the moment. However you can try finding that yourself with Reflector, dotPeek or any other disassembling tool. Library should be in your \bin folder already, called Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll

Comment: Hey @Martin Miles.
Issue here with above approach  is how can we add value to Hidden Field after Submit Action in  below method-
public void Submit(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields)
Problem is we can just read the Value of the field added to the Form , We are not able to update it.
 foreach (AdaptedControlResult result in fields)
{
  // Accessing hiddden field and trying to update. 
  // result.Value is just Read only and cannot be updated

}

Comment: So my requiremnet here would be 
1) Adding some value to Hidden field or View State (not Session) before Exception is thrown by the Form.
2) Once user resubmits the Form - I need to access the above Saved value.

Comment: So you want to add hidden field wit a value after button click, but before it goes to server? Or anything else? Can you describe your goal on a higher level, for me to get an understanding why do you need such a behavior? Are you trying to create multi-step WFFM?

Comment: My basic intention is as below-1) On form submit- custom Action is called where I call Rest API.
2) If above API returns false I throw an Exception with a message to user for trying again and user is returned back to Form with values retained. In case of this i want to save GUID in some temporary variable.
3) User can resubmit-i want to access the GUID saved in step 2 and write some logic.As of now I have used HttpContext.Current.Session["SesionGUID"] to solve my purpose.But i want to get away with Session and i was thinking if i can use Hidden fields, VieState etc to solve my purpose.